# Batch file to clean one folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder on my drive, which I regulary clean.
It has only txt files with sql logs.
How can I write batch script which is going to clean it when I run it ?
What I mean is, I do not want to go to drive, look for the folder, etc. Just have a shortcut on my screen, which is going to turn batch script on.

I tried to write it myslef, and modify it a bit, but its not working.

```
`@echo off
set "search_folder=C:\path\to\folder"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%search_folder%\*.txt"') do (
  type "%%f" | findstr /v /r "^[ ]*$" > temp.txt
  move /y temp.txt "%%f"
)`
```

it does not delete anything

Comment: There can be used also just `del /A /F /Q "C:\path\to\folder\*.txt"`. There is no batch file needed at all. A shortcut file – `.lnk` file as present on your desktop and in Window __Start__ menu – with property __Target__ being configured as `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C del /A /F /Q "C:\path\to\folder\*.txt"` is absolutely enough and makes it possible to configure property __Run__ with *Minimized*. See also my comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75279813/how-to-silently-run-a-batch-file-every-5-minutes) if a scheduled task should be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is how you schedule a batch https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7
2. Code to delete bunch of files https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-delete-all-particular-files-inside-a-folder-in-windows-10/